# how to hide table in B.I.R.T after accessing data from that table

Tags: birt

I need to hide that table once the high chart is plotted in html page. i m plotting high chart using that data. if anyone has some idea please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

select table which is needed to be hidden. then in "onPrepare" event just say.
this.getStyle().display = "none";